# Controller 404 Page Not Found [Extension Dev]

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, extensions

I am learning from tuts+ premium tutorials.
i am using this link to get some output

```
http://127.0.0.1/folder/mage3/index.php/demo/index/sayHello
```

my xml file in `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <tutsplus_demo>
            <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TutsPlus_Demo</module>
                        <frontName>demo</frontName>
                </args>
            </tutsplus_demo>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

`IndexController.php` file code

```
<?php

class TutsPlus_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function sayHelloAction() {

        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I want Hello world! in output but its showing me 404 page.

Comment: try using `<demo>` instead `<tutsplus_demo>` in `config.xml`. Also try with changing name to `Tutsplus` instead `TutsPlus`. Clear cache too

Comment: instead of `echo` please use `Mage::log(print('Hello World', true));` and don't forget to enable log in admin backend. check your log file `var/log/system.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Tutsplus_Demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Tutsplus_Demo>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tutsplus_Demo>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php   
class Tutsplus_Demo_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

}
```

**app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Tutsplus_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Demo"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("demo", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Demo"),
                "title" => $this->__("Demo")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Tutsplus_Demo>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tutsplus_Demo>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <demo>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Tutsplus_Demo</module>
            <frontName>demo</frontName>
          </args>
      </demo>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <demo>
              <file>demo.xml</file>
            </demo>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <demo>
        <class>Tutsplus_Demo_Helper</class>
      </demo>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <demo>
        <class>Tutsplus_Demo_Block</class>
      </demo>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Tutsplus/Demo/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Tutsplus_Demo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**app/design/frontend/customtpackage/theme/layout/demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <demo_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="demo/index" name="demo_index" template="demo/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </demo_index_index>   
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/customtpackage/theme/template/demo/index.phtml**

```
<?php echo "Hello word";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this file along with directory naming structure.In your case its important to take care of it.

1) **app\etc\modules\TutsPlus_Demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TutsPlus_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TutsPlus_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) **app\code\local\TutsPlus\Demo\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <tutsplus_demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TutsPlus_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>demo</frontName>
                </args>
            </tutsplus_demo>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

3) **app\code\local\TutsPlus\Demo\controllers\IndexController.php**

```
class TutsPlus_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function sayHelloAction() {

        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to identify you mistakes.

Following is the output which i get from above code.

[image]

Comment: sir i did the same.. no show!! :(

Comment: can you please update the question along with directory structure means path

Comment: ok try this files https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BweKwHQ_asV2OFZZSEdNdXhoMjQ